# About accessing premium sms in Samsung j7pro

Tags: sms

On my J7 phone under Apps, Special Access, Use Premium text message service, it is not showing my messaging service, so I can't set it to Always Allow.so how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

The app needs to request "Premium SMS" at least once before it will start showing up in *Use premium text message service*
So, first try to send a premium SMS using your messaging app and then the app will be available for you to make the permanent choice.